# Trying to get from the Azure DevOps API the execution history for a TestPoint

Tags: rest, azure-devops-rest-api

I can see the execution history from this page: [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_testPlans/_results?testCaseId={testcaseid}&contextPointId={pointid}](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_testPlans/_results?testCaseId=%7Btestcaseid%7D&contextPointId=%7Bpointid%7D) but I cannot find a way to get that same history from the API. Any suggestions?